# Google map loads the locations too slow

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to pass an arrayList which contanis 3 elements with this data `lat, long, route, direction` as intent from my `GETLLRD` class  to the `Map` activity to display the locations in google map but I am facing problem that the google map loads the locations too slow. Does anyone see where there problem is?

I appreciate any help.

**GetLLRD class:**

```
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Map.class);
                    intent1.putExtra("list_data", data);
                    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                                  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent1);
```

**Map activity:**

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    private boolean initMap() {
        if (map == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            map = mapFrag.getMap();
        }
        return (map != null);
    }


    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, String route_direct) {
        final float zoom = 11;
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions().title(route_direct)
                    .position(ll).visible(true);

            Marker marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
            map.moveCamera(update);
            System.out.println("test from Map end gotoLocationp(): ");

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<ItemDTO> list = (ArrayList<ItemDTO>) intent
                .getSerializableExtra("list_data");
        for (ItemDTO itemDTO : list) {
            double latitude = itemDTO.getLatitude();
            double longitude = itemDTO.getLongitude();
            int route1 = itemDTO.getRoute();
            String route = Integer.toString(route1);
            String direction = itemDTO.getDirection();
            String route_dirc = route + ", " + direction;
            if (initMap()) {
                gotoLocation(latitude, longitude, route_dirc);

            }

        }
    }

}
```

**map.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```